# bash aliases in xargs: "bash -c" does not pass arguments to command

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

To recognize aliases in "xargs", I have set an alias

```
alias xargs="xargs bash -ic"
```

If I now execute the below snippet, no arguments are passed to the command to xargs.

```
find . -name pom.xml | xargs grep projectid
```

Infact, no arguments are passed to the command even in this case.

```
bash -ic grep projectid pom.xml
```

The documentation for bash says

```
-c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first  non-option      
          argument  command_string. If there are arguments after the command_string, they 
          are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.
```

So what am I doing wrong?

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.39(2)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
```

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to @knittl for his inputs. A work around solution for now to avoid all the extra punctuations in @knittl's answer.
1. Download [xargs_bash_alias.sh](https://github.com/KiranMohan/scripts/blob/master/xargs_bash_alias.sh)
2. Set an alias

```
alias xargs="<path>/xargs_bash_alias.sh"
```

Now your xargs commands would recognize your other bash aliases.

Comment: `bash -c grep projectid pom.xml` executes the command `grep` and has the positional arguments `$0` (projectid) and `$1` (pom.xml`). The positional arguments are unused by your command.

Comment: You do know that `"$*"` will not properly work for multi-word arguments?

Comment: I am not aware of it. Not a bash guru. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: See my answer, I do not understand why it will not work for your scenario

Comment: Ur answer works. I did thank u for ur inputs :-). I wanted to avoid all the extra punctuations in the command. With that script I can just type "find <whatever> | xargs grep <word>". So now "grep --color" will be used if the bash alias is set.

Comment: My answer also contains the fix for your `"$*"` bug and an explanation.

Comment: @knittl - fixed it. check here [xargs_bash_alias.sh](https://github.com/KiranMohan/scripts/blob/master/xargs_bash_alias.sh)

Comment: I'm not sure it works with a script. You lose the ability to have filenames with spaces in them (and quoting becomes tricky really quickly!). Furthermore, your `xargs`-alias prohibits you from passing arguments to xargs directly (such as the very helpful and important `-0` switch)

Comment: Your script also imposes several restrictions on the arguments that you can pass to `xargs`: no whitespace, no shell metacharacters, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent comments. Will fix the script when I get time. May be I can modify xargs itself to recognize bash aliases.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you need to be aware of. First, proper quoting:

```
find . -name pom.xml -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c "grep projectid"
```

Second, you need to pass your positional arguments somehow:

```
find . -name pom.xml -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c 'grep projectid "$@"' -
```

Use `-` as first argument to bash, so positional arguments start at `$1`, just like in a normal shellscript.

`"$@"` expands to quoted positional arguments starting from 1.
Since xargs passes multiple arguments at once, you either need to use `"$@"` (quoted!) inside your bash script or run xargs with the `-n1` option.

Comment: That said, in your example, you don't need bash at all. Just use plain xargs: `find . -name pom.xml -print0 | xargs -0 grep projectid`

Comment: aliases set in bashrc are not recognized by xargs. hence I need to use "bash -ic". Read that somewhere.

Comment: @KiranMohan: you and I are not using aliases inside xargs.

Comment: lets say i have set "alias grep='grep --color'". xargs will not use the aliased version of grep.

Comment: @KiranMohan: yes, but that was not part of your question.